# Blank page after refresh react firebase authentication

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-context

[image: firebase-db]

I have the above firebase db. I want to extract the displayName value and use it in a greeting message after the user is successfully login (e.g. Hello George!). I manage to achieve this but when I refresh the page everything disappears and in console I get this error "index.esm2017.js:1032 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')".
Is this a problem of how I extract the displayName from firebase document?
Can someone explain to me what is the problem, please?

[image]

Here is my code:

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const signIn = (email, password) =>
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      console.log(currentUser);
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const logOut = () => signOut(auth);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, signIn, logOut }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

WelcomePage.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import { db } from "../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";
import { doc, Firestore, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const WelcomePage = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});
  const { user } = UserAuth();  

  useEffect(() => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        setUserDetails(docSnap.data());
        console.log(docSnap.data());
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, {userDetails.displayName}!</h1>
    </div>    
  );
};

export default WelcomePage;
```

Comment: Where is the code that is having a problem with reading `indexOf` from an undefined object? Can you edit the post to include the complete error message and code stacktrace if it exists? Maybe you only want to do the document fetch in `WelcomePage` if there is a user `uid` value to fetch with.

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks for your feedback! I edited the post and attached a picture with the errror. It looks like the problem is in WelcomePage at const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);. I think when I refresh the page the user uid is not available. But how can I preserve the username for displaying it? I am a beginner, so sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @DrewReese, after rereading your answer, I achieve to do what I want. Just put if (!user.uid) return; in useEffect and it works fine. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might only want to fetch documents in the `WelcomePage` component if there's a truthy `uid` value to use.

```
const { user } = UserAuth();

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

    try {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      setUserDetails(docSnap.data());
      console.log(docSnap.data());
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  if (user?.id) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [user]);
```